# How to transfer e-mails and contacts from Outlook Express 6 to Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-express

I would like to transfer my e-mails and contacts to Outlook 2013 on a Windows 8 laptop from Outlook Express 6 on a Windows XP PC. I have saved my email folders to a USB-Stick but am not sure how to import them into Outlook now. Assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a File-> export -> Messages|Contacts Menu?

Then in outlook you import those same files.